# How to create an Apache Virtual Hosts for a non-local website?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, web-config, localhost

I installed Apache on my local machine. I created 2 Apache virtual hosts with conf files for www.mysite.local and www2.mysite.local. I followed this tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Now I would like to create a conf file for www.google.com and display a message writing in the index.html file. I followed the same tutorial, I created a index.html file in /var/www/www.google.com/public_html/, I created a file www.google.com.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available, I edit my local file adding www.google.com on my VPS IP address. But google didn't display the message I want and display an error : "Your connection is not private".

This process doesn't work because it's not a local site? Do you know if there is an other process to configure non local websites?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your browser will have cached that `www.google.com` has [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), so it will only connect to that site with HTTPS. For what you're trying to do, which is to have a faked domain, why not use the explicitly non-real domain `example.com`?